# Why is this Runnable ran on the main thread after the being posted by a Handler constructed with a Looper from a HandlerThread?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

Hi I'm having trouble setting up a thread to run some code that requires a thread with a looper. The task will take a while and it can't be on the main thread. I've done a lot of Google searching but I can't seem to get this to work. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
private HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("My HandlerThread");
handlerThread.start();

Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            checkIfWeAreOnMain();
        }
    });

void checkIfWeAreOnMain() {
    if(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()){
        //I'm getting true here
    }
}
```

Comment: you must be calling `checkIfWeAreOnMain` from some other place, if you would call it only from a `run` method of posted `Runnable` your `Thread.currentThread()` would return something like this: `Thread[My HandlerThread,5,main]`

Comment: @pskink You're right, this ISNT on the main thread. The problem is , I had code above the " if(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread())"  line.  That code was messing up the logic of where checkIfWeAreOnMain is called. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A Handler will always run on the thread you're starting it from. It was designed to do that.

If you need something to be run on the background with some really nice and easy callbacks, use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

Comment: I am connecting to S Health datastore and synchronously writing few days of data with Samsung's HealthData sdk. This only takes a few seconds but it requires a thread with a looper.

Comment: Running the code for a synchronous insertion(m_resolver.insert(request).await();)  in an AsyncTask still throws the error " await can't be called on the main thread" . And thats from within the DoInBackground method. Is this not a situation where I simply need to kick off a thread with its own looper and do my insertions?

Comment: `A Handler will always run on the thread you're starting it from. It was designed to do that.` no, read the docs: """`public Handler(Looper looper)` Use the provided `Looper` instead of the default one."""